# $ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(\tan(x)) - \tan(\sin(x))}{ \sin^{-1}(\tan^{-1}(x)) - \tan^{-1}(\sin^{-1}(x)) }$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

My attempt:
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(\tan(x)) - \tan(\sin(x))}{ \sin^{-1}(\tan^{-1}(x)) - \tan^{-1}(\sin^{-1}(x)) }  = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$

then we try to work
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{ \cos(\tan(x)) \sec^{2}(x) - \sec^{2}(\sin(x)) \cos(x)   }{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1- (\tan^{-1}(x))^{2}} (1+x^{2})} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}} \left[ 1+(\sin^{-1}(x))^{2} \right]}  } $$

and since $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sin(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x$, then it becomes

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sec^{2}(x) \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{ \cos(\tan(x)) -  \cos(x)   }{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1- (\tan^{-1}(x))^{2}} (1+x^{2})} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}} \left[ 1+(\sin^{-1}(x))^{2} \right]}  } $$

$$ = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{ \cos(\tan(x)) -  \cos(x)   }{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1- (\tan^{-1}(x))^{2}} (1+x^{2})} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}} \left[ 1+(\sin^{-1}(x))^{2} \right]}  } $$

then also $\sqrt{1- (\tan^{-1}(x))^{2}}$ and $1+(\sin^{-1}(x))^{2}$ converge to $1$, so the above is just

$$ = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{ \cos(\tan(x)) -  \cos(x)   }{ \frac{1}{(1+x^{2})} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}} }  } $$

$$ = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0 } (\sqrt{1-x^{2}} (1 + x^{2} ) \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{ \cos(\tan(x)) -  \cos(x)   }{ \sqrt{1-x^{2}} - 1 - x^{2}  } $$

$$ =  \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{ \cos(\tan(x)) -  \cos(x)   }{ \sqrt{1-x^{2}} - 1 - x^{2}  } $$

Using L'hopital approach for the above, we work on:

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{ \sin(x) - \sin(\tan(x)) \sec^{2}(x)   }{ -\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} - 2x  } $$

but also $\tan(x) \rightarrow x$ as $x \rightarrow 0$, so we will end up

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}  \frac{ 1 -  \sec^{2}(x)   }{ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} - 2  } = 0$$

But the answer should be $1$, what rules do I violate and why?

Comment: $\tan(x)\to x$ as $ x\to 0$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A clarification in a limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3970974/a-clarification-in-a-limit)

Comment: @macton maybe $\lim \tan(x) = \lim x$ more appropriate

Comment: One cannot replace $\sin x$ with $x$. In fact $$\cos(\tan(x)) \sec^{2}(x) - \sec^{2}(\sin(x)) \cos(x)=-\frac{7}{16}x^6+\cdots$$ $$\cos(\tan(x)) \sec^{2}(x) - \sec^{2}(x) \cos(x)=-\frac{1}{3}x^4+\cdots$$ Since the denominator is of order $x^6$, it makes all the difference.

Comment: According to WolframAlpha your answer starts going wrong by assuming $\sqrt{1- (\tan^{-1}(x))^{2}}$ converges to 1. As this limit will L'Hôpital forever some techniques are needed. Possibly hard to find though...

Comment: It is so simple composing Taylor series.